# Why is letrec necessary when we already have let?

Tags: scheme

In R7RS-small section 4.2.2 *Binding constructs*, there is an example of `letrec`:

```lisp
(letrec ((even?
          (lambda (n)
            (if (zero? n)
                #t
                (odd? (- n 1)))))
         (odd?
          (lambda (n)
            (if (zero? n)
                #f
                (even? (- n 1))))))
  (even? 88))
```

I don't understand why `letrec` is necessary when we already have `let` in the language. I tried to replace `letrec` with `let`, and I got the correct value (`#t`) in MIT Scheme 11.2, Racket 7.2 `plt-r5rs`, Chez Scheme 9.5, and Guile 3.0.1. What is the real use of `letrec`?

```lisp
(let ((even?
       (lambda (n)
         (if (zero? n)
             #t
             (odd? (- n 1)))))
      (odd?
       (lambda (n)
         (if (zero? n)
             #f
             (even? (- n 1))))))
  (even? 88))
```

Comment: The reason your second version is working is because it's calling the built-in `even?` and `odd?` procedures.

Comment: Try it again but with functions that don't already exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`letrec` Can't be replaced by `let` like that.  It 'works' in your case because your local bindings are shadowing global bindings, which are then being called in the calls which look, but are not, recursive.  Consider instead

```
(let ((factorial
       (λ (n)
         (if (<= n 1)
        1
        (* n (factorial (- n 1)))))))
  (factorial 10))
```

If you try to evaluate this you will get an error.  But, if you use `letrec`, you won't:

```
(letrec ((factorial
          (λ (n)
            (if (<= n 1)
                1
                (* n (factorial (- n 1)))))))
  (factorial 10))
```

is fine.

Of course, you can in fact get away without `letrec` if you are willing to use something pretty much equivalent to the U combinator by passing the function itself as an argument:

```
(let ((factorial
       (λ (c n)
         (if (<= n 1)
        1
        (* n (c c (- n 1)))))))
  (factorial factorial 10))
```

But, well, you also don't need `let`: almost everything is just a syntactic convenience.